# Access SharePoint document library using ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sharepoint-online

I have developed an ASP.Net MVC application which is Azure Single-Sign-On supported.

In the existing application, I wanted to consume online SharePoint REST API's to work with the document library(Get folders/files,upload, add, replace and delete etc.)

Is there any way to do/achieve this task.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

yes, the supported way is to use [SharePoint CSOM](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM/16.1.20211.12000) which is now in .net standard. Please see [this article](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/blogs/net-standard-version-of-sharepoint-online-csom-apis/) were you may find a movie that shows the whole process to add nuget, authenticate the app and get some data from SharePoint, and here is he [msdn support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/using-csom-for-dotnet-standard).
Some [CSOM examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-client-library-code) how this works