# Accessing Sharepoint via Visual Studio "App is not allowed to call SPO with user_impersonation scope"

Tags: azure, sharepoint-online

I have an ASP.Net Core MVC web app which talks to Sharepoint Online using the Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client package.

This had always been working fine deployed in Azure and also when debugging locally in Visual Studio. However it seems about a month or so ago the ability to debug in Visual Studio stopped working. I am not sure if it is to do with my set up  or something deprecated.

Before I would open up Visual Studio Command Prompt and type `az login`

This would then set the access token. In my code I have the following method to get the token:

```
private async Task<string> GetToken()
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_token))
            {
                var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
                _token = await azureServiceTokenProvider
                    .GetAccessTokenAsync(_sharePointSettings.BaseUrl);
            }

            return _token;
        }
```

I then supply this token into my request such as this:

```
public async Task<Stream> DownloadStreamAsync(string url)
        {
            EncodeUrl(ref url);
            var token = await GetToken();
            var contextPath = _sharePointHelper.GetClientContext(url);
            using (var ctx = new ClientContext(contextPath))
            {
                ctx.ExecutingWebRequest += Spcontext_ExecutingWebRequest;
                var file = ctx.Web.GetFileByUrl(url);
                ctx.Load(file);
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();

                var mstream = file.OpenBinaryStream();
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();
                var ms = new MemoryStream();
                mstream.Value.CopyTo(ms);
                ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                return ms;
            }
        }
```

This all still works on the published Azure web app, but if I am debugging locally I now get "401 Unauthorized" with this response:

```
{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"App is not allowed to call SPO with user_impersonation scope"}
```

As far as I know this approach has been fine before, but no longer. From my understanding when I use az-login the Azure CLI creates a dummy app registration, so I cannot add user_impersonation to it as it is not a 'real' app registration that shows up in Azure. AzureServiceTokenProvider gets the token that was set by Azure CLI.

Reaching out to Stackoverflow in case anyone knows if something has changed on how this is supposed to be done. My end goal is to have my user context passed into the sharepoint client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error "***App is not allowed to call SPO with user_impersonation scope***" usually occurs when you are trying to access SharePoint using invalid permissions.

- The access token doesn't contain required Microsoft Graph SharePoint API permissions to perform the action.
- The access token contains `user_impersonation` and this doesn't allow to call SPO.
- This results in ***"401 Unauthorized"*** error.

Hence as a workaround, try creating the **Azure AD Application** and grant the required **Microsoft Graph SharePoint API permissions**:

[image]

> My end goal is to have my user context passed into the SharePoint client.

As a workaround, you can try generating the token using **Authorization code flow**:

**To authorize the users**, use below endpoint:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/2773f7fd-d343-4afe-8230-e735719f9b0b/oauth2/v2.0/authorize? 
client_id=98c852b9-872c-461b-ae16-4dd7ce6cac4c
&response_type=code  
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query  
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
&state=12345
```

The **auth-code** will be generated:

[image]

I generated the **access token** via Postman using below parameters:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
grant_type:authorization_code
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
code:code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
client_secret:ClientSecret
```

[image]

When I decoded the token, **scopes** are displayed successfully:

[image]

By using the above access token, **I am able to access SharePoint** by using below sample query:

```json
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/SiteID
```

[image]

To do the same in `asp.net` mvc app, refer this [**Blog**](https://kumarshivam-66534.medium.com/implementation-of-oauth-2-0-using-authorization-code-grant-flow-479713b5fba) by Kumar Shivam.

**References:**

[Access SharePoint document library using ASP.Net MVC - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63772763/access-sharepoint-document-library-using-asp-net-mvc) by Adam

[Accessing SharePoint Data Via Graph API](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/accessing-sharepoint-data-from-azure-function-via-graph-api/) by Siddharth Vaghasia